# Can I post a string-array over HTTP-POST without using a serializer-function?

Tags: php, http-post

How can I post a string-array over HTTP-POST without serializing (Edit: without using a serializer function)? E.g.:

```
 $d1 = array ("2","5","1","3");
```

Comment: Do you mean post it from Formular or by CURL?

Comment: As Quentin has said, you can't. One silly of doing this, though, would be to concatenate the strings in the array to one long string using a unique character as the separator and `POST`ing it. Then you can explode it in your PHP code. I don't advise it though because the string may get too long for a `POST` value (I'm not sure if there's a max length) and unique characters are not easy to come by, especially as you are concatenating strings.

Comment: I many times send data as an array to php by formular simply by:
<input type="text" name="a[]" value="c" />
<input type="text" name="a[]" value="b" />
....

Comment: Yeah SoftQuide, I'va found a similar solution with multiple select boxes and already implemented it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, You can..

It works within a multiple select box. Array elements are the option-values.

Comment: That serializes it to the string `selectname=value&selectname=otherValue`.

Comment: @Quentin, that's the desired behavior, posting data in this form `d1[]=16&d1[]=18&d1[]=22` is practical an array. The variable name is always the same and the values change. Even if it is not an array which you know from JavaScript, it is a kind of array and it does the work like an array. Therefore, that is a correct answer..

Comment: @LonelyProgrammer — It gives you the behaviour you asked for while doing the one thing you explicitly said was unacceptable in the question.

Comment: To my way of thinking you are simply too tough with the interpretation ;)

Answer (score 6):

You can't.

Before serializing, the data is just a bunch of bytes in memory which won't make any sense if copied wholesale to another computer and which can't be expressed in HTTP.

This is what serializing is for.

It is much like why we use spoken language (serialization) like English (JSON) or German (WWW URL Form Encoding) to communicate between people (computers) through the air (HTTP), instead of copying the electric impulses from one brain to another (i.e. we don't have a means to do it, and impulses that work in one brain probably won't work in another).